# Timestamp on Live video after transcoding from RTSP stream to FLV

Tags: flv, rtsp, transcode

I have access to an RTSP stream from an IP camera, and the RTSP packets have video timestamps in the header.

If I transcode the video stream to FLV using VLC for the purposes of playing the video on the web, is it safe to assume that I will lose the timestamp information in the transcode process?

If so, is there any way around this?